# Missing 1 required positional argument: 'test_y'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, deep-learning, mnist

I make MNIST dataset study by MLP.
However, there is an error of missing 1 required positional argument: 'test_y'
I can't handle this problem.

Please tell me how to deal with this error message.

This is a code of what I do.

```
def homework(train_X, train_y, test_X, test_y):

epoch = 10000
batch_size = 20
learning_rate = 1e-3
input_size = 784
hidden_size = 100
output_size = 10
data_num = train_X.shape[0]

np.random.seed(0)
W1 = np.random.randn(input_size, hidden_size)
b1 = np.zeros(hidden_size)
W2 = np.random.randn(hidden_size, output_size)
b2 = np.zeros(output_size)

def softmax(x):
    x -= np.max(x, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))

def cross_entropy(y, output):
    batch_size = y.shape[0]
return -np.sum(np.log(output[np.arange(batch_size), y])) / batch_size

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def forward(x):
    fwd = {}
    fwd['h1'] = sigmoid(np.dot(x, W1) + b1)
    fwd['prob'] = softmax(np.dot(fwd['h1'], W2) + b2)
return fwd

for n in range(epoch):
    loss_sum = 0
for i in range(0, data_num, batch_size):
    x = train_X[i:i+batch_size]
    y = train_y[i:i+batch_size]
fwd = forward(x)
loss_sum += cross_entropy(y, fwd['prob'])

grad = network.gradient(x, y)

for key in ('W1', 'b1', 'W2', 'b2'):
    network.params[key] -= learning_rate * grad[key] 

loss = network.loss(x, y)
train_loss_list.append(loss)

if np.mod(n, 1000) == 0:
    pred_y = np.argmax(forward(test_X)['prob'], axis=1)
    accuracy = f1_score(test_y, pred_y, average='macro')
print("epoch: %5d, loss_sum: %.5f, accuracy: %.5f" % (n, loss_sum, accuracy))

pred_y = np.argmax(forward(test_X)['prob'], axis=1)
return pred_y

from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import numpy as np

def load_mnist():
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
mnist_X, mnist_y = shuffle(mnist.data.astype('float32'),
                           mnist.target.astype('int32'), random_state=42)

mnist_X = mnist_X / 255.0

return train_test_split(mnist_X, mnist_y,
            test_size=0.2,
            random_state=42)

def validate_homework():
train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = load_mnist()

# validate for small dataset
train_X_mini = train_X[:100]
train_y_mini = train_y[:100]
test_X_mini = test_X[:100]
test_y_mini = test_y[:100]

pred_y = homework(train_X_mini, train_y_mini, test_X_mini)
print(f1_score(test_y_mini, pred_y, average='macro'))

def score_homework():
train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = load_mnist()
pred_y = homework(train_X, train_y, test_X)
print(f1_score(test_y, pred_y, average='macro'))

validate_homework()
# score_homework()
```

Comment: The problem is here `homework(train_X_mini, train_y_mini, test_X_mini)` and `homework(train_X, train_y, test_X)` - your `homework` method requires 4 arguments, but you are only passing 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did your answer, another error happened.
Where should I insert "global x"?

     <ipython-input-12-1b079a8ccba7> in homework(train_X, train_y, test_X, test_y)
     17     def softmax(x):
     18         x -= np.max(x, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
---> 19     return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
     20 
     21     def cross_entropy(y, output):

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment